# UIRefreshControl glitching in combination with custom TableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm having a weird issue where an `UIRefreshControl` is glitching when I use it in combination with an `UITableView` and custom `UITableViewCells`. If I use basic ones (set in the inspector panel in Xcode) it works just fine. See [GIFs on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDvHv.jpg).

[image: Normal behaving refresh control with cell style set to basic]
[image: Glitching refresh control with cell style set to custom, containing a simple UILabel]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl

    refresh()
}

@objc func refresh() {
    tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    return cell!
}
```

Settings in inspector on UITableView and UITableViewCell are default. I'm having this issue in multiple project. The code above is in a clean project. The refresh control also jumps when `prefersLargeTitles = false`.

How do I get the refresh control to behave correctly with a custom TableViewCell?

Comment: Please include the image in your post and on an external site

Comment: @slashburn I don't have an high enough reputation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I avoid the above glitch nowadays is by delaying the tableView.reloadData() call for a small amount of time:

```
self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
self.tableView.perform(#selector(self.tableView.reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.05)
```

Not really a fix but more of a hack in my opinion.

Comment: It didn't work for me :( Do you have another suggestion?