# UIRefreshControl endRefresh jumps when used with Large Title enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to use `UIRefreshControl`, but when I call `endRefreshing()` it jumps the `UINavigationBar`. The problem only happens when I use `UIRefreshControl` along with large titles. 
Looking at some similar issues ([UIRefreshControl glitching in combination with custom TableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760383/uirefreshcontrol-glitching-in-combination-with-custom-tableviewcell)) reported here, I tried to refresh only after dragging ends, nevertheless, the bug still occurs. Also tried to use

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` and `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

But, none of the solutions found on other questions seems to resolve the problem, it still not smooth.

The video of what is happening:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BBRnZ444bE

The app delegate

```swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
        ) -> Bool {

        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.title = "My Nav"
        nav.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        nav.viewControllers = [ViewController()]
        window.rootViewController = nav

        self.window = window
        return true
    }

}
```

Observe that I'm using large titles:

```swift
        let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.title = "My Nav"
        nav.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

The `ViewController`:

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation

final class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let randomHeight = Int.random(in: 100..<300)

    init() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Try to refresh"

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        registerCells()
        setupRefreshControl()
    }

    private func registerCells() {
        self.collectionView.register(
            Cell.self,
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell"
        )
    }

    private func setupRefreshControl() {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector(refreshControlDidFire),
            for: .valueChanged
        )
        self.collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }

    @objc private func refreshControlDidFire(_ sender: Any?) {
        if let sender = sender as? UIRefreshControl, sender.isRefreshing {
            refresh()
        }
    }

    override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if collectionView.refreshControl!.isRefreshing {
            refresh()
        }
    }

    private func refresh() {
        if !collectionView.isDragging {
            collectionView.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
            collectionView.perform(#selector(collectionView.reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.05)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int
        ) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath
            ) as? Cell else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        cell.label.text = "Text number \(indexPath.row), with height \(randomHeight)"
        cell.heightAnchorConstraint.constant = CGFloat(randomHeight)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}

final class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private let shadowView = UIView()
    private let containerView = UIView()
    private let content = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    var heightAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        insertSubview(shadowView, at: 0)
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(label)
        containerView.addSubview(content)
        activateConstraints()
    }

    private func activateConstraints() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        shadowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        shadowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        shadowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        shadowView.bottomAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 14

        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        let widthAnchorConstraint = containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20)
        widthAnchorConstraint.identifier = "Width ContainerView"
        widthAnchorConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        widthAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        content.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        content.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        heightAnchorConstraint = content.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 220)
        heightAnchorConstraint.identifier = "Height Content"
        heightAnchorConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        heightAnchorConstraint.isActive = true
        content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        content.backgroundColor = .red

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        applyShadow(width: 0.20, height: -0.064)
    }

    private func applyShadow(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, cornerRadius: 14.0)
        shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        shadowView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)`

When we use `AutoLayout` to resize the cell, it creates a bug with `UIRefreshControl` and navigation bar large title. So, if you use `layout.estimatedItemSize` with an equal or greater size than we expected. So the bug will not happen and the glitch will not happen.

Basically, the problem is when we call `updateData` but the cell is bigger than we expect and each cell of the `UICollectinView` will resize to a bigger size then the `UICollectionViewController` will glitches.

Answer (score 0):

So, I try your code and all works fine.

But I ran it on iPhone 7 - no large title there.

I think, it is `largeTitle` issue.

You can try use this code snippet:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Comment: thanks! however, I would like to know how to use the `UIRefreshControl` with `largeTitle`. I know that the issue is related to the large titles, but I would like to know how to resolve it.

Comment: oh. so sadly :(

Comment: I updated the question with the navigation controller as well, showing that I'm using `navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

Comment: I found out the problem and answer here :D it was related to the auto resize of the cell. @Davydov Denis